# Android gradle свой тип ресурсов

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle, android-resources

Можно ли как-то сделать свой файл ресурсов, что бы можно было получать данные по аналогии с строками (R.custom.field1), и при этом соблюдались все те же правила что и для других ресурсных. Сейчас я использую xml, перепаковываю и использую. А в R.string не хочется запихивать, так как цели у этих данных разные, хоть и выглядят одинаково.

Comment: А какого рода данные вы хотите хранить и что именно хотите этим добиться? Если строки и цель - просто хранение отдельно от основных строк - то сохраните их в отдельный файл. Обращение, правда, будет так же как и к обычным строкам через R.string. Прямо совсем свой тип ресурсов, вроде, нельзя сделать да и не очень понятно зачем.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб суть в том что эти ресурсы(строковые) вносятся человеком далеким от программирования, и часто в них есть повторы с теми с у меня используются для интерфейсных целей, по началу я так и делал, просто добавлял суфиксы, но это оказалось очень неудобным решением, так как там много всего, и оно часто меняется (Там сводки статей, словарь терминологии и т.д.). Я написал скрипт который вытягивает все это с базы, и форматирует мне в удобный для меня ресурсный вид на многих языках. Так же предлагал сделать подгрузку, но руководство требует оффлайн решения.